# Is sharing service account keys a viable method of sharing data between work groups using Google Sheets? Is there a better way?

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, google-api, gspread

I wrote a Python program that sends location information to a Google sheet through a service account key (.json). I'm using gspread for this. I modified the program to share with another group, and they use their own Google account along with their own service account key and sheet. I want to be able to query their sheet for data and have them query mine. However, this would require me to have a copy of their .json file in my program folder... So, we'd have two keys in a single folder. Is this safe? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you're using a service account you can just make another class for your other spreadsheet url. Just make sure that the account is added to both spreadsheets.